# How to use read_html to read a table with 2 class attrs?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the prices of fund in:

http://www.prudential.com.hk/PruServlet?module=fund&purpose=searchHistFund&fundCd=JAS_U

but the class attribute of the rows in table are different, there are "class":"fundPriceCell1" and "fundPriceCell2":

```
<tr>
<td align="center" class="fundPriceCell1">08/11/2013</td><td align="center" class="fundPriceCell1">118.2500</td><td align="center" class="fundPriceCell1">118.2500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" class="fundPriceCell2">07/11/2013</td><td align="center" class="fundPriceCell2">118.9800</td><td align="center" class="fundPriceCell2">118.9800</td>
</tr>
```

How do I scrape the table? It is wrong but how to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = 'http://www.prudential.com.hk/PruServlet?module=fund&purpose=searchHistFund&fundCd=JAS_U'
tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, attrs={"class":"fundPriceCell1"})
```

Comment: If your back-end html parser is beutifulsoup, I guess you can pass along a compiled regex as the value of the 'class' element in your attrs dictionary

Comment: This is a dictionary of attributes that I can pass to use to identify the table in the HTML.  How can I pass along a compilied regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can pass along compiled regex and that this syntax will match the two `class` attributes:

```
import re
tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, attrs={"class":re.compile("fundPriceCell\d+")})
```

Comment: Now I got:   AssertionError: No tables found

Comment: You also get that error with the constant you put in your post, but it is not related to what you ask to resolve.